# How can I add a country flag to drop down menu next to counrty name in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image

I  have a dropdown menu with two countries and want to add the country flag to the left of the country name. I chose Canada to be the default country. I am unsure how to add the image in.

```
my code :
class Country  extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "Canada" };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
          <option value = "United States">United States</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Country;
```

Comment: select element is not going to show images. So not possible

Comment: do you have any suggestions what else i can do?

Comment: Code your own selection element or use one of the thousands out there.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create your own base of countries flags, you can use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-flags-select

Answer (score 0):

Here i used emoji as opposed to the images i don't know how much this will be helpful:

```js
class Country  extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "Canada" };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value="Canada"> { '\uD83C\uDDE8\uD83C\uDDE6' } Canada</option>
          <option value = "United States">{'\uD83C\uDDFA\uD83C\uDDF8'} United States</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Country/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```